# Retrieving Column names as per Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net

I am using MS Excel as my datasource. I have one table in one of the workbook. When I retrieve the data from table I need column name as per MS Excel (e.g. A, B, C,... AA, AB... and so on.)

Is there any way to achieve it?

Please guide me.

Comment: The column names are always fixed in Excel. One of teh possible ways can be to get the column number and pass it to a function which will return the actual coulmn name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy
I made a method once for this, all you need is a column number and it will convert it to a string as "aa" or "bb"

```
private static string chars ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

private static string ConvertNumber(int number)
{
  string result;
  number -= 1;
  int rest = number % 26;
  int q = number / 26;
  if(q == 0)
  {
    result = chars[rest].ToString();
  }else{
    result = ConvertNumber(q) + chars[rest];
  }
  return result;
}
```

This only works when your first column isn't index = 0, but index = 1.
That is because the 'A' is not the same as a '0' like in the normal numeral systems.
If it where then AB would be 0 * 26^1 + 1 * 26^0

Comment: Thanks a lot for wonderful input and such a timely reply :) :) cherio

Comment: @PriyankThakkar: np, i had this code sitting in on off my projects here. Copy paste and some comments and its done :)